# update brothers objects from react

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and want to implement a basic nav side bar which has some items, I want to make the last one I clicked to have className active and all the others not.

In the following code I cannot remove className in resetALL with item.setState (yeah by read the doc I understand it doesn't work), so I tried to manipulate the dom directly using jQuery. it works on the first click but the second click has no effect. Is there any react native way to do this? Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var NavItem = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return this.props.item;
            },

            handleClick: function() {
                React.render(<span>{this.props.item.description}</span>, document.getElementById('main'));

                this.props.resetALL();
                console.log("this", this);
                this.setState({active: true});
            },

            render: function() {
                var className = this.state.active ? "active" : "";
                return <li className={className}><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.item.description}</a></li>;
            }
        });

        var NavBar = React.createClass({
            items : [],

            resetALL: function() {
                this.items.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log("item", item);
                    // item.setState({active: false});
                });

                $("#nav-sidebar li").each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                });
            },

            render: function() {
                var _this = this;

                this.props.items.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log("handleClick", this.handleClick);
                    _this.items.push(<NavItem item={item} key={item.id} resetALL={_this.resetALL}/>);
                });

                return (
                    <ul className="nav nav-sidebar" id="nav-sidebar">
                        {this.items}
                    </ul>
                );
            }

        });


        var NAVLIST = [
            {id: 1, description: 'OverView', active: true},
            {id: 2, description: 'Calls'},
            {id: 3, description: 'Channels'},
            {id: 4, description: 'OverView'}
        ]

        React.render(<NavBar items = {NAVLIST} />, document.getElementById('sidebar'));


        React.render(
            <h1>Hello, FreeSWITCH!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('main')
        );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When `NavItem` calls `this.props.resetALL()`, the function isn't bound to `NavBar`, so it can't iterate through the `NavBar`'s items. You could bind it to the correct scope like this:

```
<NavItem item={item} key={item.id} resetALL={_this.resetALL.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see some stuff in your code that is a little uncommon in react:

- re-rendering the `main` element every time an event occurs kinda defeats the purpose of react.js. Instead you should communicate via properties and events and let `react` to update the text you want in `main`
- `NavItem` should not be responsible for setting its active state, `NavBar` is a more appropriate place since it holds the other items and it can easily activate/deactivate the needed one
- I'd recommend saving the `items` array into `state` instead of a member variable, as any time you want to activate another item you simply update the state
- pushing react components in `_this.items.push` is simply the react way, you should not need to directly store and access the components
- directly manipulating DOM elements rendered by react will interfere with react
- also you don't need `$(document).ready()`

Below you can find a react.js natural approach to your problem. Three things to notice here:
1. data goes down, events go up
2. `setState` is used to let react know that something changed
3. There is an aggregate `App` component that help you updating the text

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
    itemClicked: function(ev) {
        var items = this.state.items;
        var clickedId = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-item-id");
        var activeItem = {};
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            if(item.id == clickedId) {
                activeItem = item;
            }
            item.active = item.id == clickedId;
        });
        //let react do the work
        this.setState({items:items});
        if(this.props.onItemChange) {
            this.props.onItemChange(activeItem);
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {items: this.props.items};
    },
    render: function() {
        var navItems = this.state.items.map(function(item, idx) {
            var className = item.active ? "active" : "";
            return <li key={item.id}  className={className}><a href="#" data-item-id={item.id} onClick={this.itemClicked}>{item.description}</a></li>;
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <ul className="nav nav-sidebar" id="nav-sidebar">
                {navItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }

});

var App = React.createClass({
    handleItemChange: function(item) {
        this.setState({selectedItem: item});
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {selectedItem: {description:"Hello, FreeSWITCH!"}};
    },
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <h1>{this.state.selectedItem.description}</h1>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <NavBar items={this.props.items} onItemChange={this.handleItemChange} />
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
});


var NAVLIST = [
    {id: 1, description: 'OverView', active: true},
    {id: 2, description: 'Calls'},
    {id: 3, description: 'Channels'},
    {id: 4, description: 'OverView'}
]

React.render(<App items = {NAVLIST} />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. ottonomy's solutions works for me for now. I'll eventually use an App to track everything I think.

Comment: Well, you don't need to track everything, but it would be good to :)

Comment: Well, I means it could track everything if I want. As you mentioned I re-render the main element each time when an Item is clicked, it's like switching pages. It works though not the purpose of react. But Navbar and main elements are two different elements and I have to use sub PubSub of window.addEventListener to make them talk to each other as mentioned by http://maketea.co.uk/2014/03/05/building-robust-web-apps-with-react-part-1.html . If wrap everything in App we could use some parent/children callbacks, but I'm afraid when the children tree get too deep? which is the best practise?

Comment: Don't worry about performance, `react` has a lot of optimisations, and event with a tall tree it works very well

Answer (score 0):

You're right to be suspicious of using jQuery to update classes on DOM elements managed by React. Whenever React re-renders, your jQuery changes will usually be overwritten. To use React well, you have to do a lot of thinking and rethinking of what you are trying to represent with your application, and where the data that defines its state should naturally live.

In this example, you're trying to render a list of navigation links where only one of them is active. The NavBar is a more reasonable place to store which item is active than the NavItem's state.

I recommend passing in the list of items as props to NavList, and storing the initially active item in NavList's state or passing it in as a clearly labeled initiallyActiveItem like this:

```
<NavList items={NAVLIST} initialActiveItem={1} />
```

But the id of the active item should be stored in NavList's state, not props, so one way of doing this would be to use NavList's getInitialState lifecycle method to initialize the active item:

```
getInitialState: function() { return { activeItem: this.props.initialActiveItem }; },
```

When you need to update the active item, like in a click handler, you can use a setState call, like `this.setState({activeItem: 2}`

I'd define a function on NavList that takes an id and calls its setState method to set the active item to that id, then pass that function down as a prop to each item (In this line `this` is the NavBar instance, and `item` is one element of `this.props.items`):

```
<NavItem id={item.id} update={this.updateActive} key={item.id} active={this.state.activeId == item.id} />
```

NavItem only needs to know whether its props.active is true in order to decide whether to render the active className, and how to pass its id back up to NavBar's updateActive function in order to make itself active if it isn't already. When NavBar updates, it will re-render its children NavItems, and they'll be updated with the proper active status so they can render themselves the proper classNames.

Of course, if the purpose of clicking NavItems is to do more than just update whether or not that item is active, you will have to make sure that any other relevant actions will be triggered by that click. If that means updating the content of a completely different React component, like what you've rendered into #main, think of where you will store and retrieve the state information about what should be in that other component. It likely should be a parent of both of these elements, or some other shared stateful resource, like a Flux Store. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html for some more about how to reason about where this information lives.